# How to explain what the symbolic definition of into is doing?

Tags: functions

So I came across this symbolic definition of into     $$\{\forall x_1, x_2, \in X, f(x_1) = f(x_2) \rightarrow x_1 = x_2 \}$$

and really liked it. But its hard for me to explain why. So I am going to try to explain why I liked it to you guys. It defines "into" by providing an example of the only time where two values of the range would equal to one another.

This definition does two things:

1. Makes clear that each range value is distinct from one another
2. And shows the only logical time they wouldn't be.

All in one statement.

Is there a name for what this definition is doing that I like? It is very concise and not like other definitions I've seen. Where you kinda have to poke at more exercise problems to get all of the edge cases and the likes. I am an undergrad and have never taken a proof class, if that information helps.

Comment: Could you think of any less likeable definition of the same concept?

Comment: Where did you come across this? Even ignoring the spurious right brace, it's gibberish: what do those commas mean and what are $i$ and $j$? The correct formula that characterizes a 1-1 or injective ("into", if you like) function  $f$ on some set $X$ is $\forall x, y \in X(f(x) = f(y) \to x = y)$, i.e., for every $x$ and $y$ in $X$, if $f(x) = f(y)$ then $x = y$.

Comment: @RobArthan hope the edit clears it up!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I found one that I don't think is as good. Here: The range of f consists of all elements y in Y such that y = f(x) for some x in X.

Comment: The edit still leaves the spurious right brace and doesn't answer the question of where you came across this.

Comment: @RobArthan Sorry I'm writing this on my phone in a bus so editing is a pain and I cant link stuff. I changed the definition a little to make it clearer, but I see now that it just made it more confusing. I put it back to the original version.

Comment: OK. So now you have the standard way of asserting that a function $f$ on a set $X$ is 1-1. I agree with you that it is very neat. So what is your question about it?

Comment: @RobArthan Is there a name for how the definition goes about defining itself? It defines itself using an example of when the range values wouldn't be distinct. When the main take away of into is that the range values are always distinct. An example of what I mean is  Kind of like how when you proof something, you can prove it by contradicting it and the name given to that is proof by contradiction.

Comment: I see. I think that the term you may be looking for is [universal quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification), which gives you a way of stating what is required in **all** examples.

Comment: @RobArthan I think it may be. The Wikipedia article seems to be exactly what I'm looking for in encapsulating a definition into a statement. I'll have to read it more, thanks.